# ¿Como dibujar un marker seleccionado de una lista en google maps usando controladores angularjs (Ionic)?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic

Estoy haciendo una app móvil con [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) y tengo una lista de lugares en una vista `lugares.html`, cada ítem tiene un nombre, dirección y ubicación (coordenadas). Quiero que al seleccionar un ítem se dibuje el marcador de mi posición actual y el seleccionado. Intenté hacerlo con un `href` pasando las coordenadas por parámetros a la vista de mapa, pero solo funciona la primera vez y luego no aparece el mapa. Mi duda es en la parte de "//Dibujar marker de lugar", no se si ponerlo en una función, como llamarla.. Soy nuevo en esto. si necesitan alguna otra parte de código me avisan. (Aclaro que estoy usando `tabs` y el mapa es una pestaña y lugares es otra). También me gustaría saber si estoy haciendolo de la forma correcta (usando el `href`). Agradezco su ayuda.

Archivo lugares.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Lugares">

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>

        <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="item in lugares" 
                  href="#/tab/mapa/{{item.latitud}}/{{item.longitud}}">
            <h2>{{item.nombre}}</h2>
            <h3>{{item.calle}} {{item.numero}} </h3>
            <h4>{{item.latitud}}, {{item.longitud}}</h4>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Estado del mapa

```
 .state('tabs.mapa',{
         url:'/mapa/:lat/:lng',
         views:{
            'mapa-tab':{
            templateUrl: 'templates/mapa.html',
            controller: 'ControladorMapa'
            } 
         }
 })
```

Controlador mapa

```
.controller('ControladorMapa', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation){
  // Mapa con centro en mi posicion
  var options = {timeout: 10000,  enableHighAccuracy: true};

  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

    var centro = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: centro,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  //Marcador
  // Esperar que se cargue el mapa
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){
  //Crear marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: $scope.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: centro
  });  
  //Ventana 
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Estás aqui!"
  });
  //Evento de ventana
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
  });
  // Dibujar marker de lugar
  $scope.lat = $state.params.lat;
  $scope.lng = $state.params.lng;
  if ($scope.lat != 0 && $scope.lng != 0) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: $scope.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.lng)
    });   
  } 
});
}, function(error){
  console.log("No pudimos localizarte.");
});
});
```

Comment: No tengo tiempo de probarlo pero, cambia `$scope.lat = $state.params.lat` por `$scope.lat = parseFloat($stateParams.lat)` ademas debes injectar `$stateParams`. Es necesario pues los parámetros son cadenas, no números.

Comment: Agregue el $stateParams y puse el parseFloat, pero sigue haciendo lo mismo que antes, la primera vez aparece perfecto, con los markers en su lugar, el problema esta cuando voy hacia la otra vista y selecciono un lugar, el mapa no aparece

Comment: Algún mensaje de error en la consola?

Comment: Hola Alvaro, no me aparece ningun error en la consola. Todo parece correcto, todavía no puedo solucionarlo, si queres ver alguna otra parte del codigo o alguna captura de pantalla me avisas. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Porque tienes un estado `'/mapa/:lat/:lng'` con dos parámetros latitud y longitud y no usas esos parámetros despues con `$stateParams` para poner el maker en el mapa. Estas intentando poner dos markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que angular tiene su propio ciclo de vida y los mapas de google funcionan principalmente con eventos por lo que si usas el api nativo vas a tener que estar llamando constantemente a `$scope.apply()` para sincronizar tu vista con los mapas. Mi recomendación es que uses la librería [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) que maneja todos esos detalles por tí.

Hacer un mapa con un marker es muy sencillo

*lugares.html*

```
<ion-view view-title="Lugares">

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>

        <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="item in lugares" 
                  ui-sref="tabs.mapa({lat: item.latitud, lng: item.longitud})">
            <h2>{{item.nombre}}</h2>
            <h3>{{item.calle}} {{item.numero}} </h3>
            <h4>{{item.latitud}}, {{item.longitud}}</h4>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Fíjate que cambié el `href` de tus items por `ui-sref` para manejar los estados. Esto es una buena práctica ya que si modificas la configuración de estos no hay que cambiar código en la vista para que vuelvan a funcionar.

*controller*

```
.controller('ControladorMapa', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
  // Mapa con centro en mi posicion
  var options = {timeout: 10000,  enableHighAccuracy: true};

  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position) {
        uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function() {
            $scope.map = {
                center: {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                },
                zoom: 15           
            };

            $scope.marker = {
                idKey: 1,
                coordinates: {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                },
                options: {
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon:'url/icon.png'
                },
                click: function () {
                   $scope.showWindow = true;
                }
            };

            $scope.showWindow = false;
        });   

    }, function(error){
        console.log("No pudimos localizarte.");
    });
});
```

Fíjate que yo llamo a la función `uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(...)`, la razón de esto es porque tu estas usando una animación(`google.maps.Animation.DROP`) que es un objeto nativo de los mapas y porque:

> Garantiza que angular-google-maps no comienze a procesar ninguna directiva hasta que el SDK de Google Maps esté cargado completamente!

*mapa.html*

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
    <ui-gmap-marker idKey="marker.idKey" click="marker.click"
        coords="marker.coordinates" options="marker.options">
        <ui-gmap-window coords="marker.coordinates" show="showWindow">
            <div>Estás aqui!</div>
        </ui-gmap-window>
    </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Si quieres usar el [info-window](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/window) con contenido dinámico tienes que usar la directiva [ng-non-bindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) ya que angular-google-maps las compila manualmente. Lee una explicación mas detallada en el [artículo de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757926/why-is-ng-non-bindable-required-for-ui-gmap-windows-element-in-angular-google).

No te olvides [configurar](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/GoogleMapApi) la librería en caso que necesites cambiar el comportamiento de todos tus mapas

```
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        key: 'your api key',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
});
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya lo voy a probar, estoy recién empezando con esto y no sabia que había una `API` dedicada a  `Angular`.

Comment: @Martin No te olvides votar en la respuesta y marcarla como aceptada si te pareció útil.